# Не подключается header в app.js

Tags: javascript, react-native, импорт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем, проблема заключается в том что не подключается `Header` в `app.js`.

```
import {Header} from './Header';
```

При этом ошибок по коду нет, но в если написать код `Header`-а в `App` то видны и текст и цвет текста

Речь про третью и восьмую строчки кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите то что лежит в `./Header`

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. вы экспортируете по умолчанию, там надо импортировать без фигурных скобок. Фигнурные скобки используют, когда экспортируют не по умолчанию.

Т.е. если вы экспортируете так:

```
export default function Something
```

то импортировать надо так:

```
import Something from 'path/to/Something'
```

Если же вы экспортируете так:

```
export function Something
```

то импортировать надо так:

```
import { Something } from 'path/to/Something'
```